# Calculating probabilities in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know that my order requires many calculations but I hope you will see it as a challenge.

I've a table named `matchup` that looks like this:

*note: the dataype for each column (except `players`) is `decimal(5,2)`*

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|players    player1 player2 player3 player4 player5 player6 player7|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|player1    NULL    47.01   52.22   47.59   47.79   43.67   47.61  |
|player2    51.34   NULL    51.76   49.29   48.22   44.46   48.16  |
|player3    46.00   46.33   NULL    41.90   40.46   41.17   39.66  |
|player4    50.34   48.39   55.65   NULL    50.47   44.89   48.48  |
|player5    50.23   49.25   56.76   46.76   NULL    47.27   47.61  |
|player6    54.96   53.77   56.92   53.33   51.36   NULL    49.07  |
|player7    51.03   50.00   58.12   49.12   50.20   48.55   NULL   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This table shows the probabilities (in%) of each player against other players. The table should be read as follows: for example player1 has 47.01% chance of winning against player2. The probability of a player against himself does not make sense here and that data should be omitted when calculating the odds.

Imagine that you are the manager of a team and you know that your opponents team will be **composed of 1-5 players**. The players names will be given in the following variables `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, `$e`. For example, it could be `$a='player2';` `$b='player4';` `$c='player7'` (in this case we have only 3 players in your opponents team).

Given this information, the goal is to determine which are the best players to face the enemy team as well as providing their chance to win againt the other team.

In this example, the probability for each player to win against the opponent team is given by:

```
player1 = mean(47.01; 47.59; 47.61) = 47.40
player2 = cannot be chosen (because it is already chosen by the other team)
player3 = mean(46.33; 41.90; 39.66) = 42.63
player4 = cannot be chosen
player5 = mean(49.25; 46.74; 47.71) = 47.87
player6 = mean(53.77; 53.33; 49.07) = 52.06
player7 = cannot be chosen
```

This results should be presetend as an associative array with values in descending order:

```
$result = array(
'player6' => '52.06',
'player5' => '47.87',
'player1' => '47.40',
'player3' => '42.63'
);
```

Note that this table is just an extract, the code should take into account that the table may involve more than 7 players.

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: *NOTE:* This looks like a rather poor database table design. From what I can gather, it looks like you'd have to add an entire column to the table if you wanted to add a new player...I would recommend going with something like `player_id1, player_id2, probability` for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your table structure to have

**Table Player:**

PlayerID

PlayerName

...

**Table Team:**

TeamID

TeamName

...

**Table TeamMembership**

TeamID

PlayerID

**Table Probability**

Player1ID

Player2ID

Probability1Beats2

Then, assuming Team ID 1 consists of player IDs 2, 4, and 7 like your example, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT Pl.PlayerName, SUM(Pr.Probability1Beats2)/COUNT(DISTINCT(Pr.Player2ID)) AS Avg
FROM (Team T LEFT JOIN TeamMembership M ON T.TeamID = M.TeamID), Probability Pr, Player Pl
WHERE Pr.Player2ID = M.PlayerID
AND M.TeamID = 1
AND Pr.Player1ID NOT IN (
    SELECT PlayerID FROM TeamMembership M2
    WHERE M2.TeamID = 1
) 
AND Pr.Player1ID = Pl.PlayerID
GROUP BY Pr.Player1ID
ORDER BY Avg DESC
```

The query probably isn't perfect, but it should give you a lead.

Comment: I appreciate your help to try to solve this problem. However I am unable to change the structure of the table, so I have to find a solution using the table as it is. I'm sure your answer is one step closer to the solution.

Comment: So you have no database driven definition of what constitutes a player or team? Are teams just hard-coded into the app, then?

Comment: The only data I have is the one you saw in the table. The players that will play on the opposite team are given by a PHP $_POST, so they aren't hard-coded.